# ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, django

Выдаёт ошибку:

> ValueError: ModelForm has no model class specified.

urls.py:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', posts_list, name='posts_list_url'),     # Posts list
        path('post/create/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_creat_url'),     # Post create
        path('post/<str:slug>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail_url'),     # Post detail
        path('tags/', tags_list, name='tags_list_url'),     # Tags list
        path('tag/create', TagCreate.as_view(), name='tag_create_url'),     # Tag create
        path('tag/<str:slug>', TagDetail.as_view(), name='tag_detail_url')     # Tag detail
    ]
```

views.py:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    from django.views.generic import View
    from .models import Post, Tag
    from .utils import ObjectDetailMixin
    from .forms import TagForm, PostForm

    # List block
    def posts_list(request):
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/index.html', context={'posts': posts})

    def tags_list(request):
        tags = Tag.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'blog/tags_list.html', context={'tags': tags})


    # Detail block
    class PostDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Post
        template = 'blog/post_detail.html'


    class TagDetail(ObjectDetailMixin, View):
        model = Tag
        template = 'blog/tag_detail.html'


    # Create block
    class TagCreate(View):
        def get(self, request):
            form = TagForm()
            return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': form})

        def post(self, request):
            bound_form = TagForm(request.POST)
            if bound_form.is_valid():
                new_tag = bound_form.save()
                return redirect(new_tag)
            return render(request, 'blog/tag_create.html', context={'form': bound_form})


    class PostCreate(View):
        def get(self, request):
            form = PostForm()
            return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': form})

        def post(self, request):
            bound_form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if bound_form.is_valid():
                new_post = bound_form.save()
                return redirect(new_post)
            return render(request, 'blog/post_create_form.html', context={'form': bound_form})
```

forms.py:

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import Tag, Post
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    class TagForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Tag
            fields = ['title', 'slug']
            widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
            }


        def clean_slug(self):
            new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
            if new_slug == 'create':
                raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create".')
            if Tag.objects.filter(slug__iexact=new_slug).count():
                raise ValidationError('Slug must be unique. We have "{}" slug already.'.format(new_slug))
            return new_slug


    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'tags']
        widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        }

        def clean_slug(self):
            new_slug = self.cleaned_data['slug'].lower()
            if new_slug == 'create':
                raise ValidationError('Slug may not be "Create".')
            return new_slug
```

models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.shortcuts import reverse

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
        body = models.TextField(blank=True, db_index=True)
        tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
        date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


    class Tag(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('tag_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

        def __str__(self):
            return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

Comment: В `PostForm` кажется забыли `class Meta`

Comment: Добавил `class Meta`, но теперь выдаёт ошибку `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_create_url' not found. 'post_create_url' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: Ну да, у вас и в самом деле нет никакого post_create_url

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.